# Nginx, fastcgi, proxy_pass

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, fastcgi

Have 2 domains: `main.domain.com` and `sub.domain.com`

So I need `sub.domain.com` proxy pass to `main.domain.com/somepath`, but now I'm catching that `main.domain.com` works and `sub.domain.com`:

> [error] 27961#27961: *14 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)
>   while reading response header from upstream, client: ip.ip.ip.ip, 
>   server: sub.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
>   upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "sub.domain.com"

My nginx config looks like:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 1000m;
        charset utf-8;

        server_name main.domain.com;

        location / {
             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
             fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
             fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
             fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
             fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
             fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        }
    }

   server{
        listen 80;
        server_name sub.domain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/somepath;
            proxy_set_header Host main.domain.com;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for. The error is a time out issue. You might want to ref to this article first and make sure u have set enough time https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/

Comment: What protocol is running on port 8000. One server is using FastCGI and the other is using HTTP, they cannot both be right?

Comment: I've set big timeout, not helped

Comment: App based on Django running with fastcgi on port 8000. main.domain.com connect to it with fastcgi_pass. And I want to open  http://main.domain.com/somepath on http://sub.domain.com (same content response on both urls)